# VB.NET data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to implement a textbox, namely `txtSearchInput` that is able to search **Member ID** *(Auto Number)* as well as **Member First Name** *(Short Text)* from an MS Access database.

If I enter **number** into textbox to search member based on **Member ID**, I am good to go. However, I get this error message: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` if I attemp to search member based on **Member First Name**.

Is anyone free to explain to me how I should code to get this right? Also, if you guys have a link if this question previously answered or a better concept, I will highly appreciate it.

My current code:

```
Try
    'Setup Connection String
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\igcDatabase.accdb"
    sqlCom.Connection = conn

    'Open Data Connection
    conn.Open()

    'Query
    sqlCom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Members] WHERE [Member ID] = @MemberID OR [Member First Name] = @FirstName"

    'Parameter is used below to prevent SQL Injection
    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("MemberID", txtSearchInput.Text)
    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtSearchInput.Text)

    Dim sqlRead As OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

    sqlRead.Read()

    If sqlRead.HasRows = True Then

        Dim membershipType As String
        If sqlRead.GetValue(4) = 1 Then
            membershipType = "Deluxe"
        ElseIf sqlRead.GetValue(4) = 2 Then
            membershipType = "Non-Deluxe"
        Else
            membershipType = "Week-Day"
        End If

        txtMemberID.Text = sqlRead.GetValue(0)
        txtFirstName.Text = sqlRead.GetString(1)
        txtLastName.Text = sqlRead.GetString(2)
        txtGender.Text = sqlRead.GetString(3)
        txtContact.Text = sqlRead.GetValue(5)
        txtEmail.Text = sqlRead.GetString(6)
        txtMembershipType.Text = membershipType
        txtStatus.Text = sqlRead.GetString(7)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("There Is no such member found in database. Please Try again. ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        txtSearchInput.Clear()
        txtSearchInput.Focus()
    End If
    sqlCom.Parameters.Clear()
    sqlRead.Close()
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: If `Member ID` is a value, you are passing text which is a string; the full error message would say so.  You should use `Add` not `AddWithValue`  and specify the type.  And it looks like Option Strict is off

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your solution, it really helped me out a lot! And yea, the Option Strict is off. If is better to turn it on by default?

Comment: It is best to make it the permanent default for all projects: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.  May have to turn it on for the current project too: Project Properties -> Compile

Comment: @Plutonix, I just got the chance to use `Add`. Now, I got the error: `input string was not in a correct format` for the second parameter line when I swapped it to `sqlCom.Parameters.Add("FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtSearchInput.Text)`. Which part am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have two possibilities to search for, it would make sense to have two queries, the choice of which depends on if the input value is a number or not. You can use `Int32.TryParse` to check that.

Some other points:

- You should explicitly state the columns you want to retrieve from the database so that you know that they are in the order you require.
- I have used [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) blocks to ensure clean disposal of any unmanaged resources used by the database access commands.
- There is a chance that two members have the same name, you should code something to handle that situation.
- Please see the comments and TODOs in the code.

This is what I came up with (untested):

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
'...
Sub x()
    Dim criterionValue = txtSearchInput.Text
    Dim colsToRetrieve = "[Member ID], [Member First Name], [Member Last Name], [MembershipType], [Gender], [Contact], [Email], [Status]"
    Dim memID As Integer
    Dim sql As String
    Dim param As OleDbParameter

    ' Use different queries depending on if the user entered a number to search for or text.
    If Int32.TryParse(criterionValue, memID) Then
        sql = "SELECT " & colsToRetrieve & " FROM [Members] WHERE [Member ID] = @MemberID"
        param = New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@MemberID", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer, .Value = memID}
    Else
        sql = "SELECT " & colsToRetrieve & " FROM [Members] WHERE [Member First Name] = @FirstName"
        'TODO: set .Size to the size declared in the database
        param = New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@FirstName", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 50, .Value = criterionValue}
    End If

    ' let the ConnectionStringBuilder take care of any quoting of the path...
    Dim connStr As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
    connStr.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    'TODO: move the database to somewhere it will work properly,
    ' see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
    connStr.DataSource = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "igcDatabase.accdb")

    Try
        ' use Using to take care of disposing of conn and sqlCmd...
        Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr.ConnectionString)
            Using sqlCmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param)
                conn.Open()
                Dim rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

                If rdr.HasRows Then
                    Dim rowCount As Integer = 0

                    While rdr.Read()
                        Dim membershipType As String

                        Select Case rdr.GetInt32(4)
                            Case 1
                                membershipType = "Deluxe"
                            Case 2
                                membershipType = "Non-Deluxe"
                            Case Else
                                membershipType = "Week-Day"
                        End Select

                        txtMemberID.Text = rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString()
                        txtFirstName.Text = rdr.GetString(1)
                        txtLastName.Text = rdr.GetString(2)
                        txtGender.Text = rdr.GetString(3)
                        txtMembershipType.Text = membershipType
                        txtContact.Text = rdr.GetString(5)
                        txtEmail.Text = rdr.GetString(6)
                        txtStatus.Text = rdr.GetString(7)

                        rowCount += 1

                    End While

                    If rowCount > 1 Then
                        'TODO: Do something more useful than tell the user, e.g. present all the records.
                        MsgBox("More than one record found. Only the last is shown.")
                    End If

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no such member found in database. Please try again. ", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                    ' User may have mis-typed just one character, don't make them type it all again
                    'txtSearchInput.Clear()
                    txtSearchInput.Focus()

                End If

                rdr.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will definitely try it out and mark answer as answered once I get back to my computer.